# Cookie NaN error on first visit

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

On first visit it to my site, there is no cookies set, so my calculation return a NaN error. How can I solve this (If no cookie, return a 0 instead).

This is what I use to get the cookie.....

```
$scope.WH1 = parseInt($cookies.get('WH1'));
$scope.WH2 = parseInt($cookies.get('WH2'));
$scope.WH3 = parseInt($cookies.get('WH3'));
$scope.WH4 = parseInt($cookies.get('WH4'));
$scope.WH5 = parseInt($cookies.get('WH5'));
```

and to set it I use .....

```
$scope.saveInCookie = function() {
$cookies.put('WH1', $scope.WH1);
$cookies.put('WH2', $scope.WH2);
$cookies.put('WH3', $scope.WH3);
$cookies.put('WH4', $scope.WH4);
$cookies.put('WH5', $scope.WH5);
```

My fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/Lvrr0nzc/21/show

I did try || 0 in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If no cookie, return a 0 instead

With the [curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html):

```
$scope.WH1 = parseInt($cookies.get('WH1')) || 0;
$scope.WH2 = parseInt($cookies.get('WH2')) || 0;
$scope.WH3 = parseInt($cookies.get('WH3')) || 0;
$scope.WH4 = parseInt($cookies.get('WH4')) || 0;
$scope.WH5 = parseInt($cookies.get('WH5')) || 0;
```

That works because `NaN` is falsy and `||`, so `NaN || 0` is `0` because the result of `||` is the value of its first operand if that value is truthy, or the value of the second operand otherwise.

Or you could use `||` earlier in the process:

```
$scope.WH1 = parseInt($cookies.get('WH1') || "0");
$scope.WH2 = parseInt($cookies.get('WH2') || "0");
$scope.WH3 = parseInt($cookies.get('WH3') || "0");
$scope.WH4 = parseInt($cookies.get('WH4') || "0");
$scope.WH5 = parseInt($cookies.get('WH5') || "0");
```

That relies on the value from `$cookies.get()` being falsy (`null`, `undefined`, `""`) if the cookie doesn't exist, which it *probably* is, and so `value || "0"` gets either the value from the cookie or the string `"0"`.

But I'd probably use the first one.

Comment: thanks, i put the || 0  in the wrong place, I did $scope.WH1 = parseInt($cookies.get('WH1'  || 0));

Comment: It seems to work on my fiddle but not on my page. http://www.ahoymearty.co.uk/basebubble/

Comment: what am i doing wrong... on the fiddle it worked fine, but not on my live site ?

Comment: @Wayne: Clearly you're doing something different. So use the debugger built into your browser to see what's going wrong.

Comment: i added the || 0  as suggested and that was all i needed to add to each cookie, i added the same || 0 to my live and it still didnt put the 0 in.

Comment: looking at the debugger, it isnt showing the ||0 in the code, but when i view source of the JS its in there